# Meaning of どこでなく

Tags: grammar

> カムパネルラも知っている、それはいつかカムパネルラのお父さんの博士のうちでカムパネルラといっしょに読んだ雑誌のなかにあったのだ。**それどこでなく**カムパネルラは、その雑誌を読むと、すぐお父さんの 書斎{しょさい}から 巨{おお}きな本をもってきて、ぎんがというところをひろげ、まっ黒な 頁{ページ}いっぱいに白い点々のある美しい写真を二人でいつまでも見たのでした

What does `どこでなく` mean here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「それどこでなく」 is an informal way of saying 「それどこ**ろ**で**は**なく」.

「それどころではない」 is a set phrase meaning 「その程度{ていど}ではない」.  It means that something goes way beyond a certain point.

In the context of the passage, it is referring to カムパネルラ's degree of interest in the subject -- the Galaxy.  S/he was not satisfied with the information from the magazine, so s/he went to her/his father's study to grab a big book to read more about it.

Comment: Oh god that is so perfect! I forgot about the first part of the quote!!!! Thank you thank you!!!!

Comment: I have never seen or heard それどこでなく. Do you know それどこでなく is (or was) commonly used somewhere in Japan, by people other than Miyazawa?

Comment: 森鴎外「そう。わたし見なかったわ。それどこじゃないのですもの。」([『心中』](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000129/files/690_23035.html)) とか・・・ 平山千代子「隣の智ちやんが、それどこぢやないといふ様に心配して」([『カイダイ』](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/001292/files/47161_29948.html))・・・島崎藤村「それどこじゃ無いぞや」([『家』](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000158/files/1510_40740.html))・・・谷崎潤一郎「私はなかなかそれどこやあれしませんさかい」([『卍』](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/001383/files/56873_62035.html)) ・・・ 徳田秋声「それどこじゃないわ。私あの人たちに顔も合わせられないわ。」([『仮装人物』](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000023/files/1699_46893.html)) とかどうでしょう・・・（「それどこ**で**ない」じゃなくて「それどこ**じゃ**ない」ばっかりでしたけど‥）

Comment: @Chocolate おお、そんな言い方があったんですね…全然知りませんでした

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Chiebukuro thread](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1326581563), this それどこ may be either a typo for, a dialectal version of, or the author's own idiosyncratic version of, それどころ.  See [the J↔E entry in Weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%85%B6%E3%82%8C%E5%87%A6).

Comment: Then it would be "of course it was Campanella"?

Comment: @AlbertoAndrade: Ah, no, it would be more like what l'électeur has posted.  _"That's the kind of thing that was in the magazines that her father the professor read together with Campanella.  **Far from just that** / **Not just** / **Even more than that**, when she'd read those magazines, Campanella would go to her father's study..."_  See also [this other Weblio hit](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/それどころで), which explains this slightly better than the link in my post above.

Comment: Thank you!!! All of you!